# Mvc HtmlHelper chaining to generate Dropdown Submenu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, delegates, html-helper, chaining

I am developing a web application using MVC4 with Twitter Bootstrap. I want to create a custom dropdown menu HtmlHelper similar to this one *(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc, and search 'dropdownmenu')* to generate a parent menu and its child sub menu items.

I don't want to use this TwitterBootstrapMvc extensions because I need to have custom actions inside the Helper method.

**Details**

I have a parent menu (let's call it Utility), and under that I want to generate dropdown submenus like the following:

```
-- Utility
------ Shipping Lot
------ Receiving Lot
------ Meeting
```

Basically Utility is a controller and the sub items are its actions.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Shipping Lot</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Receiving Lot</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Meeting</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**My Questions**

1. How can I write the HtmlHelper method so that it can accept a dynamic list of other actions? For example: I would like to have a HtmlHelper method that can do this

   ```
   @html.DropdownMenu("Utility", "Index", "Utility", "[Area]", "[iconClass]",
       menu => {
           menu.SubmenuItem("Shipping Lot", "ShipLog", "Utility", "[Area]" ...)
           menu.SubmenuItem("Receiving Lot", "ReceiveLog", "Utility", "[Area]" ...)
           menu.SubmenuItem("Meeting", "Meeting", "Utility", "[Area]" ...)
       }
   )
   ```
2. Where can I find tutorials on HtmlHelper with chaining or maybe it's called with delegates?

Hope my questions are clear. This is my first time to post questions here.

Comment: Could you post html sample of what you need to get at the output?

Comment: It would be just simple unordered list. Something like: `<ul class="nav nav-list"><li class="active"><a href="#">Shipping Lot</a></li><li><a href="#">Receiving Lot</a></li><li><a href="#">Meeting</a></li></ul>`

Comment: I have a working solution already. But I just want to learn how to write a Html extension that can figure out active link based on the current area and current controller and add the "active" class to the li item.